# Another manner to swap the contents of two variables?

Tags: c, pointers, swap

Yesterday, I've seen the following function.

```
static void swap (int *p, int *q) {
    *p -= *q;
    *q += *p;
    *p = *q - *p;
}
```

In which case this function does not work? I think there is potentially an overflow problem, and it can be also inefficient. Is there anything else?

Comment: XOR trick maybe? Note: p and q *could* point to the same object.

Comment: Yes, those are precisely the problems, overflow and aliasing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the aliasing case.

Comment: I am sure that your computer is able to handle the extra (8?) bytes to store a temporary variable. But one imagines it is a homework question.

Comment: It was just a personnal question, I read several solutions to swap two variables, and I've never seen this method before. So I asked why.
It is not an homework. ;)

Comment: @EdHeal: also, the compiler is usually able to detect the swap with a temporary variable and convert it in a single appropriate assembly instruction (if available).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overflow issue is not a "maybe", it's there for sure: when you exchange a high-magnitude negative with a large positive, you get an overflow, which is undefined behavior according to the standard.

But most importantly, there is absolutely no point to use this (or the xor trick) in place of the usual exchange (through a temp variable) for reasons of readability.

Comment: `0x7FFFFFFFE` needs 35 bits, you have overflow already on initialisation. If you initialise `p` and `q` with numbers not needing more bits than the width of `int`, you have undefined behaviour on overflow, but if the behaviour happens to be wrap-around, it works.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're so right, I should have counted my bits more carefully. Thank you very much for the correction!

Comment: You should have compiled with all warnings. If your compiler is any good, it would have warned you about "overflow on initializaton" ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer I used ideone for this, it hides warnings on compiles w/no errors :)

Comment: Ah, yet another reason for "Do it yourself".

Answer (score 1):

Actually the above answer is wrong. It gets 0xFFFFFFFE for p because it initialized q with 0x7FFFFFFFE which does not fit and is (except for undefined behavior) in fact truncated to 0xFFFFFFFE.

So the code in that answer in fact starts with p = 0xFFFFFFFF and q = 0xFFFFFFFE and successfully swaps them.

(edit: it WAS wrong, it has been corrected now)

The routine in fact works perfectly (except for eventual undefined behavior which I'm not sure is there or not, I'm a bit fuzzy on the details of the standard).

Ignoring eventual undefined behavior, if the underlying arithmetic is the common 2's complement modulo arithmetic, the routine works and have no problems with overflows/underflows (it's a modulo arithmetic).

The only real problem is with aliasing. If the two pointers are identical, the pointed to integer will become 0.

The precondition of the routine is therefore that the two pointers are valid and not aliased. Checks for null pointers and for identical pointers may be added, if that's what you expect your program to need.

The question of why to use this mechanism instead of the xor trick instead of the temp variable swap, is still open. But has NOTHING to do with the OP question: the routine works and overflow, as it's handled by 2's complement modulo arithmetic, which is the most common on processors, is not an issue (edit: it becomes only because of overflow being undefined behavior in the standard, but it works on any processor that uses 2's complement modulo arithmetic). As for efficiency, it all depends on the optimizer AND the processor.

Comment: Overflow of signed integers is undefined behaviour, that it works on most systems makes it all the more insidious, since one may grow to expect it to work. (And the mistake has long been corrected, so your answer is out of date in that respect.)

Comment: I did write "Ignoring eventual undefined behavior" exactly for that reason. You are right that one may grow to expect it (undefined behavior means anything could happen, including working as intended), but the point is that the processor arithmetic makes that algorithm valid. It's only the fact that overflow is undefined behavior in C despite the fact that all machines use modulo arithmetic that makes it questionable. As for the fact that the mistake has been corrected ... it wasn't when I started writing. I'm a slow typer, sorry.

Comment: The Overflow remark was because you wrote "which I'm not sure is there or not", just to clarify, not a criticism. As for the slow typing, I can sympathise, I'm slow too. Regarding "despite the fact that all machines use modulo arithmetic", that's the catch, not _all_ do, there are ones' complement machines out there still, unfortunately.

Comment: Do machines that use ones' complement for signed integer arithmetic still use modulo arithmetic for unsigned integers? If so the algorithm could be written with unsigned integer pointers and would work (in fact even work if the pointers point to something that is not a signed integer, as long as the size is equivalent). It's the _modulo_ arithmetic that makes it work, not the 2's complement (problem with 1's complement is that it's not a modulo arithmetic). I admit now I'm just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes, for unsigned integers, the standard mandates arithmetic modulo `2^WIDTH`, so for `unsigned*`, the only problem is aliasing (and of course, the pointers must be valid). Using `unsigned*` to swap variables of other types would however again be undefined behaviour (but, the only way for it to fail that is a practical possibility, as far as I know, is the compiler making optimisations based on assuming strict aliasing).

Comment: Actually I think the reason the standard says it's undefined behavior is that not all cases can be covered. Imagine a structure containing pointers to it's own members. It will not fit in an `unsigned` so it's not the case here, but it's the kind of problem the standard needs to stay clear of.